# Need ssh-agent running under Apache PHP script

Tags: php, apache, ssh-agent

i want to run a capistrano command in a PHP scipt executing under apache. i need SSH-Agent started when i issue the command. Apache runs under the www-data user which has ssh-agent setup but ssh-agent is not available when running any command under PHP & Apache

is there a way to have the apache user startup ssh-agent so its available? is there a nother work around?

Answer (score 0):

Start `ssh-agent` in the script that starts `httpd`.